# Laravel testing store method

Tags: php, laravel, image, testing

Hello i would like to test a store method in laravel. In the store method has simple data and image. The faker generate all data, image as well but the validator not accepte the image. Why is this happend? The faker generate correct image name and extension.

Here is the test case

```
    public function test_an_authenticated_user_can_add_new_companie () 
    {
        $companies = factory(Companies::class)->create();

        $company = $companies->toArray();

        $this->actingAs($this->user);
        $response = $this->postJson('/home/companies/create/add', $company);
        $response->assertStatus(302);
    }
```

And here is the factory

```
        'name' => $faker->company,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'logo' => $faker->image(public_path('img\logos'), 100, 100, null, false),
        'website' => $faker->url,
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#testing-file-uploads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faker saves an temporary image and gives you a [filepath](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/blob/2063ee6f95209d08d8d0bbc70393324a18c9e5b5/src/Faker/Provider/Image.php), that is not what you want.

For testing uploading of images you should use `UploadedImage::fake()` instead. As you need to fake, how an image class acts from an `API` call instead.

```
$data = [
    'logo' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('logo.jpg'),
    ...
];

$response = $this->postJson('/home/companies/create/add', $data);
```

To check that the file actually gets saved, you can fake and assert it gets done.

Before the post call.

```
Storage::fake('public');
```

Assertion after the call.

```
Storage::disk('public')->assertExists('img\logos\logo.jpg');
```

Comment: Additionally i think using factories to create input data is a bad idea, early on it seems easy, but in time your input compared to database structure will diverge. This approach i have never seen in bigger projects yet.